# Convert desktop co-ordinates to iPad screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, canvas, fabricjs

I am developing iPad application.
I already have a website where i am using an canvas for drawing.
I am converting that drawing to json data and sending that as an API response to my ipad app.
and trying to draw the drawing to ipad with the same co-ordinates.
But I am getting issues in that.
the drawing x and y co-ordinates are not proper on ipad.

Here is my json data from canvas:

```
  {  
   objects:[  
      {  
         type:"path",
         originX:"center",
         originY:"center",
         left:236.75,
         top:223,
         width:280.5,
         height:52,
         fill:null,
         stroke:"#000000",
         strokeWidth:5,
         strokeDashArray:null,
         strokeLineCap:"round",
         strokeLineJoin:"round",
         strokeMiterLimit:10,
         scaleX:1,
         scaleY:1,
         angle:0,
         flipX:false,
         flipY:false,
         opacity:1,
         shadow:null,
         visible:true,
         clipTo:null,
         backgroundColor:"",
         fillRule:"nonzero",
         globalCompositeOperation:"source-over",
         transformMatrix:null,
         lockMovementX:false,
         lockMovementY:false,
         evented:true,
         lockScalingX:false,
         lockScalingY:false,
         path:[  
            ...
         ],
         pathOffset:{  
            ...
         }
      }
```

Comment: it will be better if you can handle it from iOS side only. may this article be helpful.
https://nacho4d-nacho4d.blogspot.in/2012/03/coreimage-and-uikit-coordinates.html